# How can I store my ElasticSearch indexes/shards?

Tags: storage, cluster

I'm trying to figure out how can I store the ES indexes.
Actually I have two VMs running on 2 ESXi hosts, using 32GB vmdk...
Wondering if i could share those data or is it necessary to have duplicate storage space (NFS or ?)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to share any storage between the nodes.
What you need is to configure ElasticSearch to use its clustering features. This is very easy, check your config file and it should be very well commented.

Otherwise, do a quick google for "elasticsearch cluster", this should help you:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html

Comment: My point was to know if it would be better to share storage or to use ES clustering mecanism, which implies I'd have to duplicate storage. We're using ES to build a log console which contains lots of data (actually 1G/day but it will grow as we add servers/services to the log collect mecanism). I'll try the link you provided to understand the clustering mecanism ;)